# How to output an array with a[0] - a[0]a[1] - a[0]a[1]a[2]

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I print an array with a[0] then a[0], a[1] then a[0],a[1],a[2]....
For example.
I have an array is a[] = {1,2,3,4}
My output should be:
1
12
123
1234
Here is my code but the output is wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1,2,3,4 };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); j++)
        {
            cout << a[i] << endl;
        }
    }     
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should probably do is iterating through i, because it contains your current position in your array. you can then print the array until the i-th position .. like this :

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4};
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i ; j++)
        {
            cout << a[j];
        }
        cout << endl;       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested (based on Dominique's answer):

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1,2,3,4 };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            cout << a[j];
        }
        cout << endl; // like this, you won't go to the next line after every character.
    }     
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `std::copy`

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= 4; i++ )
{
   std::copy( arr, arr + i, std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, "") );
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

You have to include `<iterator>` header.